# Does Gatsby with Typescript Use tsconfig.json

Tags: javascript, typescript, babeljs, gatsby, tsconfig

Numerous blog posts and the [using-typescript](https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby/tree/master/examples/using-typescript) example on Gatsby JS's website show using a `tsconfig.json` file when using the automatically included [gatsby-plugin-typescript](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/plugins/gatsby-plugin-typescript/) TypeScript support for Gatsby. **I don't think the `tsconfig.json` file is being used for config, and want to ask if I'm correct.**

Gatsby uses `@babel/plugin-transform-typescript` to compile TS to JS, and that Babel plugin has [detailed docs](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-plugin-transform-typescript.html#typescript-compiler-options) on imitating the options of the `tsc` TypeScript compiler with it. The docs say this:

*Changes to your tsconfig.json are not reflected in babel. The build process will always behave as though isolatedModules is turned on, there are Babel-native alternative ways to set a lot of the tsconfig.json options however.*

**Am I missing some reason for why all of the TypeScript setups for Gatsby show a `tsconfig.json` file and config when that file appears never to be used by Gatsby?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are at least three reasons to maintain a `tsconfig.json` file in a Gatsby project:

- Testing frameworks like Jest will not use the internal Gatsby config and need some direction on what to do with TypeScript files
- Code editors like VS Code face similar limitations to Jest, so for example the TypeScript Server in VSCode needs that config
- Linting libraries like ESLint use the `tsconfig.json` file as well.

One serious issue is that using TypeScript with Babel (as Gatsby does) doesn't do type checking, so you'll get different error output from whatever you're running the Gatsby dev server on (like a console) and the other tools you're using, like VS Code's "output" tab.